# Take input as series of string till # is found in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, eclipse, while-loop

I want to take string as an input from user until "#" is the input i.e a series of string (all in different lines) till "#" is found and store the strings in an arraylist of type string. I wrote this code in JAVA but it's not working as required.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class wordMetaMorphism {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(!(sc.next().equals("#"))) {
        String s = sc.next();
        input.add(s);
    }
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

}

and i am getting this output where only the alternate strings are getting stored. I also tried sc.nextLine() but it is all same.

input - dip
lip
mad
map
maple
may
pad
pip
pod
pop
sap
sip
slice
slick
spice
stick
stock
#
#

output - [lip, map, may, pip, pop, sip, slick, stick, #]

Comment: `sc.next()` gets the next token. Every time you call it. Not the one you just read in the previous call to `sc.next()`. Variables are your friends.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Scanner;

public class wordMetaMorphism {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String s = sc.next();
        if(s.equals("#")) break;
        input.add(s);
    }
    System.out.println(input);
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are calling sc.next() and checking if that line is equal to "#", then reading the next token. This is causing it to occur with every alternate token.

You could do this:

```
String token = "";
while(!((token = sc.next()).equals("#")))input.add(token);
```

instead of the while loop you have.

Answer (score -1):

i have modified your code please check below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class wordMetaMorphism {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        String s = sc.next();
        while(!(s.equals("#"))) {
            input.add(s);
            s = sc.next();
        }
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```